# Will Kubernetes' client-go delta_fifo type cause deletion notifications to be missed?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm working on understanding `delta_fifo.go` in depth from the `client-go` project.  I'm looking at a situation where maybe reports of resource deletions might get dropped.

I'm 98% biased in favor of my own failing to read the code properly, but it seems to me that [`Delete()` will skip a deletion if it doesn't find an appropriate "event queue" (my term for `Deltas`)](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.9.0/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/delta_fifo.go#L201-L205), and [`Pop()` will remove an event queue that it is processing](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.9.0/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/delta_fifo.go#L440-L450), even if, say, the last event in the queue is an addition, update or synchronization.

Suppose you begin with an empty set of event queues (an empty `queue` and empty `items`) and then you get the following and only the following:

- an `Add()` call, which [eventually sets up or appends to an event queue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.9.0/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/delta_fifo.go#L323),
- a `Pop()` call which [pops it off and chews it up](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.9.0/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/delta_fifo.go#L442-L451), and then
- a [`Delete()` call](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.9.0/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/delta_fifo.go#L192).

Won't `Delete()` [skip broadcasting the deletion](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.9.0/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/delta_fifo.go#L200-L206), since the [relevant event queue no longer exists](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.9.0/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/delta_fifo.go#L201)?  So since `queueActionLocked()` won't be called in this case, then doesn't it follow that any downstream `ResourceEventListener`s will never be notified of this deletion?

Relatively stable links to code in question:

- `Delete`: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.9.0/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/delta_fifo.go#L201-L205
- `Pop`: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.9.0/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/delta_fifo.go#L440-L450

Any help greatly appreciated; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you highlighted in Delete() is only called when `knownObjects` is nil. The documentation for that option indicates it is used to determine what objects the consumer of the queue is aware of and if nil, indicates the consumer does not care about detecting all deletions

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.9.0/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/delta_fifo.go#L39-L42

Comment: Thanks; as discussed in Slack, and for posterity here, this differs from the case where `knownObjects` is non-`nil` but returns (effectively) an empty set of known objects.  In such a case, this empty set is regarded as its authoritative answer.  A `nil` `knownObjects`, on the other hand, is interpreted as the caller's not being interested in keeping track of such things.